# Download video from url in kotlin Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to download a video from URL. but it give an error:

> E/ContentProviderNative: onTransact error from {P:12600;U:11003}
>   2019-01-14 11:54:35.423 3518-22398/? E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI: content://downloads/public_downloads/6796
>           at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadProvider.query(DownloadProvider.java:914)
>           at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:1138)
>           at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:1230)
>           at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:251)
>           at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
>           at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:752)
>   [image]

code for downloding a video file is below:
    private var downloadReference: Long = 0
    private lateinit var downloadManager: DownloadManager

```
private val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val action = intent.action
        if (action == DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE) {
            val downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1)
            if (downloadId != downloadReference) {
                context.unregisterReceiver(this)
                return
            }
            val query = DownloadManager.Query()
            query.setFilterById(downloadReference)
            val cursor = downloadManager.query(query)
            cursor?.let {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    val columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)
                    if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == cursor.getInt(columnIndex)) {
                        var localFile = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI))

                        if (localFile.contains("file:///")) {
                            localFile = localFile.removePrefix("file:///").substringBeforeLast(File.separator)
                        }
                        //context.toast(context.resources.getString(R.string.saved, localFile), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)

                    } else if (DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED == cursor.getInt(columnIndex)) {
                      //  val message = context.resources.getString("error : ", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON)))
                        //context.toast(message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    }
                }
                cursor.close()
            }

            context.unregisterReceiver(this)

        }
    }
}

/////////// New Testing........
fun downloadFile(url: String, mimeType: String? = null) {

    val guessFileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, null, mimeType)
    System.out.println("LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL2 ");
   // Timber.d("mimeType -> $mimeType guessFileName -> $guessFileName created by url -> $url")

    val context = this

    downloadManager = context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager

    val downloadUri = Uri.parse(url)

    val request = DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri)
    request.apply {
        setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE or DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI)
        //setAllowedOverRoaming(true)
        setTitle(guessFileName)
        setDescription(guessFileName)
        setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true)
        allowScanningByMediaScanner()
        setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)

        //request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)))
        setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES, guessFileName)

        context.registerReceiver(receiver, IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE))

        downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(this)
    }
    System.out.println("LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL23 ");
}
```

Comment: on which line it gives error ?

Comment: line is not showed when error occur.

Comment: i add the screen shot

Comment: where are you creating your output file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below library:

```
  implementation 'com.mindorks.android:prdownloader:0.5.0'
```

code for downloading video from a given url is below:

```
 fun downfile(urll:String,fileName:String){



    if(!isFilePresent(fileName)) {
        var mFile2: File? = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "WallpapersBillionaire")
        System.out.println("File Foond " + mFile2!!.absolutePath)
        var mFile3: File? = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "WallpapersBillionaire")

        var downloadId = PRDownloader.download(urll, mFile2!!.absolutePath, fileName)
                .build()
                .setOnStartOrResumeListener(object : OnStartOrResumeListener {
                    override fun onStartOrResume() {
                        System.out.println("??????????????????? start")
                    }
                })
                .setOnPauseListener(object : OnPauseListener {
                    override fun onPause() {
                    }
                })
                .setOnCancelListener(object : OnCancelListener {
                    override fun onCancel() {
                    }
                })
                .setOnProgressListener(object : OnProgressListener {
                    override fun onProgress(progress: Progress) {
                        circlePeView.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                        var per = (progress.currentBytes.toFloat() / progress.totalBytes.toFloat()) * 100.00
                        //var perint = per*100
                        System.out.println("::??????????????????? Per : " + per + " ?? : " + progress.currentBytes + " ?? : " + progress.totalBytes)

                        circlePeView.setProgress(per.toInt())
                    }
                })
                .start(object : OnDownloadListener {
                    override fun onDownloadComplete() {

                        circlePeView.visibility = View.GONE
                        circlePeView.setProgress(0)
                        prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILENAME, 0)

                        val editor = prefs!!.edit()
                        editor.putString(wall, "WallpapersBillionaire/" + fileName)
                        editor.apply()

                        try {
                            val myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
                            try {
                                myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.raw.wallp)
                            } catch (e: IOException) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace()
                            }

                            val intent = Intent(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER)
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                            intent.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT,
                                    ComponentName(this@AnimattedViewpagerActivity, VideoLiveWallpaperService::class.java))
                            startActivity(intent)
                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                            val intent = Intent()
                            intent.setAction(WallpaperManager.ACTION_LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER)
                            try {
                                startActivity(intent)
                            }catch (e2: java.lang.Exception){
                                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Please long click on your home screen. Select Video Live Wallpapers form thier. Thanks",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            }

                        }
                        System.out.println("??????????????????? complete")
                    }

                    override fun onError(error: Error) {
                        System.out.println("??????????????????? error " + error)
                    }
                })
        System.out.println("??????????????????? called")
    }else{
        System.out.println("File Foond ")
        circlePeView.visibility = View.GONE
        circlePeView.setProgress(0)
        prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILENAME, 0)

        val editor = prefs!!.edit()
        editor.putString(wall, "WallpapersBillionaire/" + fileName)
        editor.apply()

        try {
            val myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
            try {
                myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.raw.wallp)
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

            val intent = Intent(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            intent.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT,
                    ComponentName(this@AnimattedViewpagerActivity, VideoLiveWallpaperService::class.java))
            startActivity(intent)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            val intent = Intent()
            intent.setAction(WallpaperManager.ACTION_LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER)

            try {
                startActivity(intent)
            }catch (e2: java.lang.Exception){
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Please long click on your home screen. Select Video Live Wallpapers form thier. Thanks",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

        }
        System.out.println("??????????????????? complete")
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1) Download Manager

The Android Download Manager was introduced in Android 2.3 as a service to optimize the handling of long-running downloads.

The Download Manger handles the HTTP connection and monitors connectivity changes. Its a good practice to use Download.

Manager in most situations, particularly where a download is likely to continue in the background between user sessions.

Instances of this class should be obtained through getSystemService(String) by passing DOWNLOAD_SERVICE.

Apps that request downloads through this API should register a broadcast receiver for ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED to appropriately handle when the user clicks on a running download in a notification or from the downloads UI.

2)Running a Service in the Foreground

A foreground service is a service that's considered to be something the user is actively aware of and thus not a candidate for the system to kill when low on memory. A foreground service must provide a notification for the status bar, which is placed under the "Ongoing" heading, which means that the notification cannot be dismissed unless the service is either stopped or removed from the foreground.

For example, Download a video from a service should be set to run in the foreground, because the user is explicitly aware of its operation. The notification in the status bar might indicate the current Download and allow the user to launch an activity to interact with Download process.

To request that your service run in the foreground, call startForeground(). This method takes two parameters: an integer that uniquely identifies the notification and the Notification for the status bar.

I have a video file(.MP4 format) and I want to allow the user to be able to download the video to their SD card.I currently use this code but its not working..

```
String PATHSdcard = "/sdcard/Video/";  

public void DownloadFromUrl(String VideoURL, String fileName)         


try { URL url = new URL("https://javmed-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/666034cbe81045f2a2da50e5205e376b.mp4");
         File file = new File(fileName);

         long sTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
         URLConnection URLcon = url.openConnection();

         InputStream is = URLcon.getInputStream();
         BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

         ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
         int current = 0;
         while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                 baf.append((byte) current);
         }

         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(PATHSdcard+file);
         fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
         fos.close();

 } catch (IOException e) {
         Log.d("ERROR.......",e+"");
 }
```

---

```
    import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;


public class VideoSaveSDCARD extends Activity{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ProgressBack PB = new ProgressBack();
        PB.execute("");
    }

    private class ProgressBack extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
         ProgressDialog PD;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            PD= ProgressDialog.show(LoginPage.this,null, "Please Wait ...", true);
            PD.setCancelable(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        downloadFile("http://beta-vidizmo.com/hilton.mp4","Sample.mp4");            

        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            PD.dismiss();

        }

    }



    private void downloadFile(String fileURL, String fileName) {
        try {
        String rootDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "Video";
           File rootFile = new File(rootDir);
           rootFile.mkdir();
            URL url = new URL(fileURL);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();
            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File(rootFile,
                    fileName));
            InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }
            f.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("Error....", e.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: i will check this. if it work then i will mark it correct.

Comment: one thing. its in java. and i need in Kotlin

Comment: int len1 = 0;
            while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }

Comment: how to convert this portion to kotlin